# Oracle count distinct record within subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery

I have 3 tables

SUBJECTS

```
CODE, SUBJECT_NAME      , SESSION
 100, MATHS             , AM
 101, MATHS - INTRO     , AM
 102, MATHS - ADVANCED  , AM
 200, ENGLISH           , AM
 201, ENGLISH - INTRO   , AM
 202, ENGLISH - BEGINNER, AM
 203, ENGLISH - ADVANCED, AM
```

STUDENTS_SUBJECTS

```
ID, SUBJECT_CODE
 2, 101
 2, 102
 1, 201
 1, 203
 3, 101
 3, 102
```

STUDENTS

```
ID,PARENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME, CLASS_LEADER, INACTIVE, EXPERT
1 , 2       , ELSA        , no          , N       , N
2 , 4       , STEVE       , no          , N       , N
3 , 5       , MIKE        , no          , N       , N
```

My query goes like

```
SELECT    t1.CODE,  
          t1.SUBJECT_NAME,
          SUM (CASE WHEN  ( (t2.CLASS_LEADER = 'no' 
                               OR t2.CLASS_LEADER IS NULL) 
                       AND t2.EXPERT IS NULL) 
              THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS "Average Student"
FROM subjects t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
              select a.STUDENT_ID, a.PARENT_ID, a.STUDENT_NAME,  
                          a.CLASS_LEADER, c.SUBJECT_CODE, a.INACTIVE, a.EXPERT
               FROM students a
               INNER JOIN  students_subjects c  
                     ON (a.STUDENT_ID = c.ID ) 
                where (INACTIVE is null)
                GROUP BY a.STUDENT_ID, a.PARENT_ID, a.STUDENT_NAME, a.CLASS_LEADER, c.SUBJECT_CODE, a.INACTIVE, a.EXPERT
) t2
ON substr(trim(t2.SUBJECT_CODE),1,2)= substr(trim(t1.CODE),1,2)
WHERE (t1.SESSION='AM') 
GROUP BY t1.CODE, T1.SUBJECT_NAME
ORDER BY T1.CODE
```

What I would like to get is the number of students who signed up for the class for morning session under each major subject without the duplicates. For example, each students who signed up for Maths - Intro & Maths Advanced should only be counted once under the Maths subject.

if I run the subquery separately minus the subject_code in select statement and group by statement, I managed to get the correct value however I'm not sure how to return the correct value when it's joined in the query.

REPORT

```
CODE, SUBJECT_NAME, AVERAGE_STUDENT
100 MATHS 2
200 ENGLISH 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit problematic that you don't have a different column for the major title. Relying on the assumption that you'll always have exactly one word for a major title, you can use string functions (SUBSTR, INSTR) to select it and then easily group by this field. However, if this title is important, I suggest you to consider the addition of another table for major titles (or perhaps another column in the subjects table, but that will result in duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some recomendation:

1) add column MAIN_SUBJECT_CODE to the table SUBJECTS (as already commented)

2) the column ID in the table STUDENTS_SUBJECTS is a foreign key pointing to the table STUDENT, so a better name will be STUDENT_ID

3) use unique mechanism to store Boolean values do not mix 'no' and 'N'

First the query of all student subscriptions

Note that I added the missing column **main_subject_code** and adjusted the average student definition to get some result.

```
 SELECT    su.CODE,  
           substr(trim(su.CODE),1,2)||'0' main_subject_code,
           su.SUBJECT_NAME,
           st.STUDENT_NAME,
           CASE WHEN  ( (st.CLASS_LEADER = 'no' 
                                OR st.CLASS_LEADER IS NULL) 
                        AND st.EXPERT = 'N' /*IS NULL*/) 
               THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS "Average Student"
 FROM subjects su
 INNER JOIN students_subjects ss
 ON  su.code = ss.SUBJECT_CODE
 INNER JOIN STUDENTS st
 ON ss.ID  /* STUDENT_ID */ = st.ID 
 ;

 CODE MAIN_SUBJECT_CODE SUBJECT_NAME              STUDENT_NAME              Average Student
```

---

```
   101 100               MATHS - INTRO             MIKE                                    1 
   101 100               MATHS - INTRO             STEVE                                   1 
   102 100               MATHS - ADVANCED          MIKE                                    1 
   102 100               MATHS - ADVANCED          STEVE                                   1 
   201 200               ENGLISH - INTRO           ELSA                                    1 
   203 200               ENGLISH - ADVANCED        ELSA                                    1
```

The rest is simple - group on main subject and add the title of it

```
 with subsr as (
 SELECT    su.CODE,  
           substr(trim(su.CODE),1,2)||'0' main_subject_code,
           su.SUBJECT_NAME,
           st.STUDENT_NAME,
           CASE WHEN  ( (st.CLASS_LEADER = 'no' 
                                OR st.CLASS_LEADER IS NULL) 
                        AND st.EXPERT = 'N' /*IS NULL*/) 
               THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS "Average Student"
 FROM subjects su
 INNER JOIN students_subjects ss
 ON  su.code = ss.SUBJECT_CODE
 INNER JOIN STUDENTS st
 ON ss.ID  /* STUDENT_ID */ = st.ID 
 )
 select 
   main_subject_code,
   (select SUBJECT_NAME from SUBJECTS where CODE = main_subject_code) main_subject_name,
   sum("Average Student") "Average Student"
 from  subsr
 group by main_subject_code
 order by main_subject_code;


 MAIN_SUBJECT_CODE MAIN_SUBJECT_NAME         Average Student
 ----------------- ------------------------- ---------------
 100               MATHS                                   4 
 200               ENGLISH                                 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted query contains a lot of extraneous logic which doesn't seem releavnt to your apparent task.  So I'm ignoring it and focusing on simply getting "the number of students who signed up for the class for morning session under each major subject without the duplicates".

```
select major
       , count(*)
from (
    select distinct subj.major
           , ss.id as student_id
    from
          ( select code, 
                  regexp_replace(subject_name, '^([A-Z]+)(.*)', '\1') major ,
             from subjects
             where session = 'AM'
           ) subj
           join student_subjects ss
                 on ss.subject_code = subj.code
    )
group by major
order by major
/
```

The subquery on SUBJECTS use a regex function to extract the leading element of the subject name as the major.  It works for the posted sample data but might fail for more complicated names.  Regex shouldn't be necessary: a proper data model would separate the MAJOR subject from its subsidiaries.